# PyQgis show SVG Symbol on differnet value of specific attribute

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, svg

I am working on a QGIS plugin. Main feature of this plugin will be changing the icons on a specific layer partly based on a specific attribute (it will be more exciting but you have to start somewhere). However, I succeed in changing all points at the layer to one specific SVG file.

After the ability of changing all points to one specific icon. I was looking around, how to change the code. But I am rather confused by the rule-based and categorized approaches. So which one should fit best to my problem and how to deal with different SVG icons. Because it looks to me that I only can use SVG icons by creating a specific layer and apply it to qgis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a night without sleep, I fixed it myself:

```
 selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.cbox_layer.currentIndex()
        selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]




        # get unique values
        fni = selectedLayer.fieldNameIndex('firebrary')
        unique_values = selectedLayer.dataProvider().uniqueValues(fni)

        # define categories
        categories = []
        determinedIcon = ""
        for unique_value in unique_values:
            # initialize the default symbol for this geometry type
            symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(selectedLayer.geometryType())

            for svgMarker in icon:
                if svgMarker[0] == unique_value:
                    determinedIcon = svgMarker[1]

            svgStyle = {}
            svgStyle['fill'] = '#0000ff'
            svgStyle['name'] = determinedIcon
            svgStyle['outline'] = '#000000'
            svgStyle['outline-width'] = '6.8'
            svgStyle['size'] = '6'

            symbol_layer = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2.create(svgStyle)

            # replace default symbol layer with the configured one
            if symbol_layer is not None:
                symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)

            # create renderer object
            category = QgsRendererCategoryV2(unique_value, symbol, str(unique_value))
            # entry for the list of category items
            categories.append(category)

        # create renderer object
        renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2('attribureName', categories)

        # assign the created renderer to the layer
        if renderer is not None:
            selectedLayer.setRendererV2(renderer)

        selectedLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Note I have a array with icons dynamically generated. The format of this array is 
icon {{attribureValue, iconLocation},{attribureValue, iconLocation}, {attribureValue, iconLocation}}